# Redux createStore is undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to learn Redux so I created a test app, but it seems like I can't apply middleware and create my store, as I get the error `'createStoreWithMiddleware' is not defined`.

My index.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Header from './components/header';
import Footer from './components/footer';
import Content from './components/content';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import ReduxPromise from 'redux-promise';
import reducers from './reducers';
import './index.css';
import './App.css';


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <Content />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </Router>
);
}}

const createStoreWithMiddleWare = applyMiddleware(ReduxPromise)(createStore);
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <App />
  </Provider>, 
  document.getElementById('root'));
```

I've tried setting Provider in the class but that doesn't seem to be working either. Probably a simple issue, thankful for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create your store, and then add the middleware:

```
const createStoreWithMiddleWare = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(ReduxPromise));
```

Your provider should then look like:

```
 <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware}>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting issues: `'Reducer' is not defined`
   `createStoreWithMiddleware is not defined`

Comment: sorry i was copy-pasting something from my own solution. Put your reducer in as the first argument - see updated code

Comment: i also suggest checking the docs for applyMiddleware: http://redux.js.org/docs/api/applyMiddleware.html

Comment: Ah. I still get the error that `createStoreWithMiddleware is not defined`, on the line `<Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>`. Cool - will read the docs.

Comment: you don't need to pass the reducer anymore as this is already done. Please see updated answer and notice the store object which is now passed to the Provider

Comment: I'm using `<Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware}>` but it still says it's undefined... It feels like it doesn't even have the library, although I thnik my imports seem OK. Could there be something else?

Comment: Oh my god.... I used a capital W in MiddleWare in my declaration but used a regular w in the call. I'm sorry for wasting your time -- appreciate the help anyways!